# ASP.NET Core Web API disabled trace request

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this VAPT comment to be resolved.

I need to disable trace option from APIs.

http methods:

```
|   Supported Methods: OPTIONS TRACE GET HEAD POST 
|_  Potentially risky methods: TRACE
```

Tried to disable from `appSettings.json` changing the log level information like this:

```
"Logging": {
 "LogLevel": {
   "Default": "Trace",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost": "None",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker": "None",
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added below code in startup file of .NET core, it solved the issue

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {               
            if (string.Equals(context.Request.Method, "TRACE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status405MethodNotAllowed;
            }
            else
            {
                await next();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure web apps and IIS to host your asp.net core web API application, I suggest you could modify the published web.config as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Core7Test.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <verbs>
                    <add verb="Trace" allowed="false" />
                </verbs>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then when you send the trace method, it will not return any value to the client.

[image]